# Remove unusful datasets after manipulation

Tags: r, database, join, merge

Is there any straightforward way to remove data that I no longer need from the environment, instead of using the rm() function?
The example here employs the join, but it can also be the basic merge()
Here is a simple example with only 2 datasets, but I actually have much more than that.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

x <- lubridate::lakers %>%
  mutate(Month = lubridate::month(lubridate::as_date(date)))

y <- datasets::airquality 

z <- y %>% 
  dplyr::inner_join(x, by = "Month")

rm(x,y)
```

Comment: something like `rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "x"))` removes all but object `x`.

Comment: No, I meant like inside the function. So each time I join (merge) two datasets, one of them will be removed without using rm(). I don't know if such a thing exists

Comment: @CatededUr yes, it is possible to do this, but it is really bad practice to automatically delete data from the calling frame as a side effect of a function.

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron. Can you please write down how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by avoiding creating objects. What I mean access dataframes within dplyr expression:

```
z <- datasets::airquality %>% 
  dplyr::inner_join(lubridate::lakers %>%
                    mutate(Month = lubridate::month(lubridate::as_date(date))), by = "Month")
```

or simplified version without specifying the packages in the code:

```
z <- airquality %>% inner_join(lakers %>%
                      mutate(Month = month(as_date(date))), by = "Month")
```

> Note: the simplified version assumes you have loaded the packages prior, while longer version assumes you have not loaded packages and thus have to speicify with "dplyr::" in front of the function or dataset.

Comment: It was only an example with built-in data. I have many files I have to load, manipulate and only then merge

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this, but it is really bad practice to automatically delete data from the calling frame as a side effect of a function.

**Please don't ever use this IRL** - it's only to demonstrate that it *can* be done, not that it *should* be done.

First we start with an empty workspace:

```r
ls()
#> character(0)
```

Now we define two data frames we are going to join in our function:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 6:10, y = 6:10)
ls()
#> [1] "df1" "df2"
```

The following function removes the input data frames from the calling environment and returns the two joined in a simple `rbind`:

```
dangerous_function <- function(data1, data2) {
  data3 <- rbind(data1, data2)
  rm(list = c(deparse(substitute(data1)), 
       deparse(substitute(data2))), envir = parent.frame())
  data3
}

df3 <- dangerous_function(df1, df2)
```

And we can see that `df1` and `df2` have indeed been deleted.

```
ls()
#> [1] "dangerous_function" "df3"
```

You could even write the function so that it deletes itself after it has been used, which would probably be for the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I take your advice and will not remove the data automatically. Anyhow, you have helped me, even by showing me how to create such a function.